# Magento replace home by category

Tags: magento2, category, home-page

my site is like a platform between multiple websites. So I don't want a homepage for each website, and I want to be directly in the first category.

How can I do that? I search for about 1h30 but find nothing wich could help me.

I know how to display custom phtml from a module on a home page, so maybe I can redirect, if I can, how I get the corresponding category of the current website?

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head over to below path.

> Store > Configuration > GENERAL > Web > Default Pages > Default Web URL

Change the value of above input with your desired Url.

for category: **catalog/category/view/id/catId"**

Replace your **catId** with your category Id.

Hope this works.